# Fixing dataset and Forecasting timeseries in Python with ARMA model

Tags: python, pandas, dataset, regression, forecasting

I have a dataset collected [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/lrp4089yv9xf1nb/comfort.csv?dl=0). First I wanted to tidy this dataset since it shows all the data in one column (instead of 10) when I use the `read_csv` from `pandas`. The output is `[8784 rows x 1 columns]` which is wrong (how can I fix this issue?)

Second, I'd like to examine a simple ARMA model on this data set just to forecast the values of `AC` column (just for myself to get familiar with this model and data analyzing) Could you please help me with some hints? How/where to start? what to do?

More info regarding the dataset: Let's say first row of this dataset shows that (e.g) on `01-01-2016` at time `00:00` when the `outside_tem` is 12 (less than x=20) and the `humidity` is 10 (less than 20) the value of `AC` is off. What will be the value of AC in similar/different conditions (humidity, out_temp, light, etc.) at 01-01-2017 at 12:00?

Answer (score 1):

use [pd.read_fwf()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_fwf.html) method:

```
In [253]: df = pd.read_fwf(r'D:\download\comfort.csv')

In [254]: df
Out[254]:
            date   time  humidity  Outside_Temperature  window  light  age  skintemp  SR  AC
0     01-01-2016  00:00        10                   12       0      1   40        45   0   0
1     01-01-2016  01:00        10                   11       0      1   40        32   0   0
2     01-01-2016  02:00        10                   15       0      1   32        40   0   0
3     01-01-2016  03:00        10                   11       0      1   15        37   0   0
4     01-01-2016  04:00        10                   11       0      1   40        33   0   0
5     01-01-2016  05:00        10                   13       0      1   15        37   0   0
6     01-01-2016  06:00        10                   11       0      1   32        42   0   0
7     01-01-2016  07:00        10                   16       0      1   15        41   0   0
8     01-01-2016  08:00        20                   25       1      2   15        36   1   0
9     01-01-2016  09:00        20                   10       1      2   32        37   1   0
...          ...    ...       ...                  ...     ...    ...  ...       ...  ..  ..
8774  31-12-2016  14:00        20                   12       1      2   15        33   0   0
8775  31-12-2016  15:00        20                    9       1      2   15        29   0   0
8776  31-12-2016  16:00        30                    8       1      3   40        38   0   1
8777  31-12-2016  17:00        30                    9       1      3   32        43   0   1
8778  31-12-2016  18:00        30                   12       1      3   40        30   0   1
8779  31-12-2016  19:00        30                    3       1      3   32        28   0   1
8780  31-12-2016  20:00        10                   11       0      1   40        41   0   0
8781  31-12-2016  21:00        10                   12       0      1   32        26   0   0
8782  31-12-2016  22:00        10                    6       0      1   40        30   0   0
8783  31-12-2016  23:00        10                    8       0      1   32        35   0   0

[8784 rows x 10 columns]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! but now when I try to group them I get error, e.g `df.groupby('date')` leads to `KeyError: 'date'` (same for other labels) why is this happening?

Comment: @SinaSh, please provide an output of `print(df.columns.tolist())`

Comment: It seems successfully did divide it into separate columns `['date', 'time', 'humidity', 'Outside_Temperature', 'window', 'light', 'age', 'skintemp', 'SR', 'AC']` but if I want to group them by let's say `AC` to see during which days and times the AC was 'on' it doesn't follow